# PostgreSQL: Function does not exist

Tags: postgresql, function

Trying to create my first PostgreSQL function, I don't understand why I can't call this function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."SampledImpCountToOriginal"(IN integer)
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN $1 > 4 THEN EXP(POW($1 - 1.88, 1/2.3)) ELSE $1 END;
END;
$BODY$;
```

`SELECT SampledImpCountToOriginal(5)`

> ERROR:  function sampledimpcounttooriginal(integer) does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT SampledImpCountToOriginal(5)
> ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. SQL state:
> 42883 Character: 8

Calling from the same database I created it in, tried changing owner, can't figure it out. The function is listed in pgAdmin as `SampledImpCountToOriginal(IN integer)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call like this - `SELECT  "SampledImpCountToOriginal"(5)`

When ever you use `Double Quotes ""` to `create Function`, you have to use in calling process. like -

```
SELECT public."SampledImpCountToOriginal"(
    <integer>
)
```

If you don't use `double quotes ""` to calling your `created function with ""`. it consider different function.

```
SELECT public.sampledimpcounttooriginal(
    <integer>
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Lifesaver. I dropped the function and redefined it without the quotes. I originally created the function with pgAdmin and it inserted the quotes... confusing behavior.